# node js update server without losing the schedule tasks?

Tags: node.js, node-schedule

I am using node js for my API and it has a schedule tasks, so when I add new feature to the project I will need to restart the server from (Digital ocean) to start this new feature, so all schedules will be gone. so How I update the project without losing them? is there's any way?

and also what is (node js pm2 restart) I can use pm2 to avoid losing schedules? or there's another ways?.

I am beginning in backend development so it's little confusing me

Comment: You have to implement hot reload of specific modules. `fs.watch` could be a good helper. Just let this watcher to observe certain modules and when it'll rise the event i.e. your module has changed, just clear previous cache and then reload with `require`

Comment: @Jaood_xD - Hot load is generally not something one uses in production because it has potential caveats and issues.  Hot load is generally a developer productivity tool, not a production tool.

Comment: @jfriend00 there is at least one enterprise solution that implements the feature in a safe way. It called 'Impress' https://www.npmjs.com/package/impress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several different approaches, but most need to use some persistent store where a newly started server can find out what tasks need to be scheduled:

1. Store all scheduled tasks in some persistent store (JSON file, database, CSV file, etc...) so anytime your server starts, it can read the previously scheduled tasks from the file at startup and reschedule them with the newly started server process.  This will also have the benefit of not losing the scheduled tasks if your server crashes unintentionally and restarts also.  The downside is that you have to regularly maintain the persistent store so that it is always up to date as new tasks are scheduled or as existing tasks complete and are done.
2. Have a way to command the server to save the currently scheduled tasks to some persistent store before you shut down your server so the server can then read them upon next startup.  This could be an admin function in your server, for example.
3. Use a scheduling module that already uses a persistent store for scheduled tasks.
4. Be able to recreate what tasks need to be run from some other data at your server startup.  You don't say what exactly your scheduled tasks are or how they come to be, but some types of schedules such as calendar reminders have an underlying store that can be queried to find upcoming tasks from scratch so you can recreate the tasks that need to be scheduled.
5. Move the tasks to a separate process that can run on its own so you are free to restart the main server without affecting the task scheduling.

Comment: What is the normal and professional way any backend uses for handle the node-schedule if he needs to update anything?

Comment: @Muhammedhamed - Which of the above options to select depends upon your app and its design and architecture.  All of these above are professional ways of handling things.  If you have #4 available to you based on other data you have stored, then that is probably preferred.  In other cases, #5 moving task running to a micro-service process can be very useful, but it adds an extra layer of process management and complication which  may not be necessary.  #1 or #3 are better than #2 because #2 can lose tasks if the server crashes unexpectedly.

Comment: @Muhammedhamed - If you can't use #4, I'd probably pick #1 or #3 and use a storage mechanism that was appropriate for the number of transactions there are.  If lots of transactions, use a database where inserts and deletes are more efficient, if not lots of transactions, use a simple JSON file that you rewrite whenever something changes.

Comment: Can you recommend any scheduling module that already uses a persistent store for scheduled tasks?

Comment: @Muhammedhamed - I am not familiar with the various module options. You'll have to do some research on NPM.